# Groovy parse XML and get Value

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm getting a XML responde like this:

```
xml = grails.converters.XML.parse( new URL( 'http://...) )
```

The XML is the following:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">272</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="indent">on</str>
<str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">roger federer</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str>
<str name="rows">10</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="29327" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">135350</str>
<int name="revision">723055</int>
<date name="timestamp">2005-08-21T22:34:05Z</date>
<str name="title">Federer</str>
<str name="titleText">Federer</str>
<str name="user">Indech</str>
<str name="userId">3073</str>
</doc>
<doc>...</doc>
 ...
<doc>...</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

And i want to store three things here:

```
<int name="QTime">272</int>
<str name="q">roger federer</str>
<result name="response" numFound="29327" start="0">
```

My output wud be:

```
def one = '272'
def two = 'roger federer'
def three = '29327'
```

How can i accomplish that=? I would appreciate some help on this. Preferebly Groovy and not Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing this might be:

```
xml = grails.converters.XML.parse( new URL( 'http://...) )

def (one, two, three) = xml.depthFirst().findAll {
  it.@name == 'QTime' || it.@name == 'q' || it.@name == 'response'
}.with { a, b, c ->
  [ a.text(), b.text(), c.@numFound ]
}

println one
println two
println three
```

But it's a bit dependent on the xml being n the order you show for the `findAll` to return things in the order required by the second bit

A more straight forward approach might be:

```
def one   = xml.lst.int.find { it.@name == 'QTime' }.text()
def two   = xml.lst.lst.str.find { it.@name == 'q' }.text()
def three = xml.result.@numFound

println one
println two
println three
```